# How to use multivator package to build a multi-output regression model in R language?

Tags: r, regression, multipleoutputs

How to use the multivator package to build a multi-output regression model in R language?
I look forward to your reply with an example. Thanks a million!

Comment: Normally we help you with the code that you already have. Could you edit your post to  have the code you have written that is not working?

Comment: The example given by the main function of the package is like this? But I want to know what this data contains? Why is it so complicated? Also is the last command is modeling?data(mtoys)
d <- obs_maker(toy_mm, toy_mhp, toy_LoF, toy_beta)
ex <- experiment(toy_mm , d)

Sigmainv <- solve(var.matrix(toy_mm,hp=toy_mhp))
multem(x=toy_mm2, expt=ex, hp=toy_mhp,LoF=toy_LoF, give=TRUE)